# Change Background image of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios5

I want to add background image to my email composer. I am using `MFMailComposeViewController`. I have tried getting the subviews of `MFMailComposeViewController`, it just returns two subviews i.e.,  a `UINavigationBar` and a `NavigationTransitionView`. `NavigationTransitionView` further conatins all the view for mail composer. I tried to customize that view but am unable t do it still. I tried getting its subviews but it returned nil.

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: That is not allowed by Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello.
>
> as your requirement to change the lay out of mail composer is not 
>   supported by the apple directly .
>
> for full fill your req you can make custom mail composer same as
>   mfmail composer with your required design and layouts in xib and you
>   can use that. but here you need to develop web service for sending
>   mail from that view.